# How do I solve a "subscript out of bounds" error?

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to produce a graph with a regression line using geom_abline() and am recieving this error:

```
Error in coef(SEC.lm)[["(intercept)"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Here is my code:

```
SEC.lm <- lm(`Elution time (sec)` ~ `ln(MW)`)

ggplot(data = calibration_data,
       aes(x = `ln(MW)`, 
           y = `Elution time (sec)`)) +
  geom_point(pch = 0) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = coef(SEC.lm)[["(intercept)"]],
              slope = coef(SEC.lm)[["`ln(MW)`"]])
```

However, when I run it I recieve the error:

```
Error in coef(SEC.lm)[["(intercept)"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I am not sure what this means or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kayley Brownbill! This is the start of a good question, but since we don't have your `calibration_data`, it's hard to know what the problem is. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (you have a good start here!), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: BTW, it seems odd to call `lm(.. ~ ..)` without any data in the call. It's generally not good practice to rely on vectors for that, too many times indexing/filtering is not consistently applied across all vectors. It's preferred to keep that data in a `data.frame` (and remove same-named vectors used to create the frame), then include that in the call to `lm`, such as `SEC.lm <- lm(\`Elution time (sec)\` ~ \`ln(MW)\`, data=calibration_data)`.

Comment: I agree with all that r2evans said, and to add, I think the intercept is usually spelled with a capitol I in R internals, and `coef` generally returns a named vector, so `coef(sec.lm)["(Intercept)"]`. In general, when you have to use backticks, save yourself the hassle and just rename your variables to a valid R names like `log_MW` and `elution_time_sec`.

Comment: Instead of `geom_abline()` its easier to use `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)`. The required coefficients are imported from the regression output object.